# Test permissions as another user?

Tags: windows, permissions

In SQL Server I can run "EXECUTE AS USER = 'someuser'" and it will restrict my permissions to whatever theirs are so I can test that I have security setup properly.

I was wondering if there is any similar ability to do this in Windows to test the folder permissions I have setup as another user? The only way I know is to create a test user with same setup as the user I want to test... hoping there is some feature like in SQL Server that doesn't require me to know the user's password to test permissions as if I were them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NTFS folders, you can check the effective ACLs in *Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Effective Access* - just select the user or group in question and *View effective access* .

Answer (score 2):

You can view the effective access just like @Zac67 described but that is not really testing your setup.

In Windows there is no way to execute a process as another user if you don't know their password.

Resetting and changing a password in Windows is not the same, so you should not just reset a user's password as an administrator unless it is just a test account.